# Printing X-type pattern in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, text, newline

I'm trying to print this pattern in Python:

```
    *............*
    .**........**
    ..***....***
    ...********
    ...********
    ..***....***
    .**........**
    *............*
```

And came up with this code that does the job:

```
for row in range(1,5):
    print "." * (row -1) + row * "*" + (16 - row * 4) * "." + row * "*"
for row in range (0,4):
    print("." * (3-row)+ "*" *(4 -row) + row * 4 * "." +"*" *(4 -row))
```

My question: is it possible to do this without using two loops? BTW, this is not for homework, I'm just playing around with some exercises from "Think Like a Programmer" by V. Anton Spraul and implementing the solutions in Python rather than C++.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without changing anything else, you can just do the loop over two ranges:

```
for row in range(1,5)+range(4,0,-1):
    print "." * (row -1) + row * "*" + (16 - row * 4) * "." + row * "*"
```

Since you can add lists together:

```
In [8]: range(1,5)
Out[8]: [1, 2, 3, 4]

In [9]: range(4,0,-1)
Out[9]: [4, 3, 2, 1]

In [10]: range(1,5) + range(4,0,-1)
Out[10]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

By the way, you can get rid of the leading dots using spaces:

```
for row in range(1,5)+range(4,0,-1):
    print " " * (row -1) + row * "*" + (16 - row * 4) * "." + row * "*"

*............*
 **........**
  ***....***
   ********
   ********
  ***....***
 **........**
*............*
```

---

A more elegant thing to do might be to build a list of strings:

```
X = []
for row in range(1,5):
    X.append(" " * (row -1) + row * "*" + (16 - row * 4) * "." + row * "*")
```

Now, add the bottom half by just duplicating the top half in reverse:

```
X = X + list(reversed(X))
```

But when we print it we see a list:

```
print X
#['*............*', ' **........**', '  ***....***', '   ********', '   ********', '  ***....***', ' **........**', '*............*']
```

So we can join them together with newlines:

```
print '\n'.join(X)

*............*
 **........**
  ***....***
   ********
   ********
  ***....***
 **........**
*............*
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know you could add ranges together like that. But as you said, since you can add lists, it makes sense.

Comment: And actually, all of the "."'s should be spaces, I was just using those to keep track of the spaces.

Comment: You can, and it explains why `[1,1] + [2,2]` is not `[3,3]`.  Also see my update for how to reverse and add the list.

Answer (score 0):

here's an answer with one while loop

```
def star(size=14): ##size for the star in your post
    asterisk=1;
    space=0;
    def func(x):
        x+=1
        return x
    def decrement(x):
        x-=1
        return x
    while (asterisk > 0):
        line=''
        line+=' '*space
        if((size-(2*space)-(2*asterisk))<=0):
            line+='*'*(size-(2*space))
        else:
            line+='*'*asterisk
            line+=' '*(size-(2*space)-(2*asterisk))
            line+='*'*asterisk
        print ''.join(line)
        if((size-(2*space)-(2*asterisk))<=0):
            func=decrement ### switch to decreasing number of asterisks after we cross the middle of the star
            print ''.join(line)
        space=func(space);
        asterisk=func(asterisk);

for i in range(20): ##whee
    star(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked askewchan's elegant approach which noticed the symmetry between the top and bottom. There is also left-right symmetry. Here's an attempt to take advantage of that (it does have two loops though):

```
stars = [" "*(row-1) + "*"*row + " "*(8-row*2) for row in range(1,5)]
for line in stars + list(reversed(stars)):
    print line + line[::-1]
```